# TempData is empty when set in a catch block and we rethrow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tempdata

I am using custom errors (`web.config`) to send unhandled exceptions to my `ErrorController`.

In my main Controller I throw an exception, catch it in a `catch` block and set the `TempData` to have some user-friendly message. I then `throw` which is then sent to the `ErrorController`.

When I check the `TempData` here, it is empty (as is the `Session` but it would be, wouldn't it?).

I am sure it is not meant to be empty, and this is the right way of sending data between controllers... but it is not working! Am I mistaken in my understanding?

`HomeController`:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    TempData["MsgForUser"] = "useful message to show";
    // Do some logging...

    throw;
}
```

`ErrorController`:

```
public ActionResult DisplayError(int id)
{
    ViewBag.MsgForUser = TempData["MsgForUser"];
    return View();
}
```

`Web.config`:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPage/DisplayError">
    <error redirect="~/Error/DisplayError/403" statusCode="403" />
    <error redirect="~/Error/DisplayError/404" statusCode="404" />
    <error redirect="~/Error/DisplayError/500" statusCode="500" />
  </customErrors>
```

Comment: @ScottWeldon Its just my preference, but the headlines from the code (ErrorController, Web.config) doesn't need to be inside a code block, it just looks a little but weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the session was being destroyed upon doing a `throw` in the top-level `catch` block, because the request to the error controller.
However I did find the returning `RedirectToAction()` preserved it.

So, I created my own exception type:

```
public class MyApplicationException : Exception
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A message that can be shown to the user i.e. not technical
    /// </summary>
    public string MessageForUser { get; set; }

    public MyApplicationException()
    {
    }

    public MyApplicationException(string message, string messageForUser="")
        : base(message)
    {
        MessageForUser = messageForUser;
    }

    public MyApplicationException(string message, Exception inner, string messageForUser = "")
        : base(message, inner)
    {
        MessageForUser = messageForUser;
    }
}
```

then when I encounter a problem that I am expecting and will end up sending the user to a generic error page, I use it like so:

```
if (MyList.Count > 14)
{
      throw new MyApplicationException("More than 14 records received: " + MyList.Count.ToString(), "There is a maximum limit of 14 records that can be processed at a time. Please call us to discuss your requirement to process in greater quantities.");
}
```

and upon catching it I pick out the message for the user, log the error, and `return RedirectToAction()` to go to the error page without losing the `TempData`.

```
catch (MyApplicationException myAppEx)
{
    // If there is a user-friendly message then store it for DisplayError to show
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(myAppEx.MessageForUser) == false)
    {
        TempData["MsgForUser"] = myAppEx.MessageForUser;
    }

    // Do some logging to elmah or a custom logger
    util.LogError(myAppEx, "MyFunc() threw an exception", args);

    //
    // We cannot throw here because we lose the Session & TempData. we have to do a manual redirect.
    //
    return RedirectToAction("DisplayError", "ErrorPage", new { id = 500 });
}
```

and finally in my view, I look for it and display if it exists:

```
<p>
    An error occurred. Please check & try again later.
</p>
@if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.MsgForUser) == false)
{
    <p class="more-info">Details: @ViewBag.MsgForUser</p>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TempData is Stable when use RedirectToAction() method , in Exception Handling does ASP.net use this method? maybe not !! 
why don't use Exception.Message to set the user friendly message ? set `ex.Message`  at your catch block , then at your error view you can access it. your error view model must be `@model HandleErrorInfo`  , and the `@Model.Exception.Message`  has your message had been set !

Comment: When I 'throw', it redirects to the Error controller (see the web.config code above). There is no exception object passed between the two controllers.

Comment: see Lab29 in this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1002109/Learn-MVC-Project-in-days-Day-6 , maybe useful

Comment: you are rigth , my solution is different one !